# Why CPU cores perform differently with the same task under multiprocessing?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, python-multiprocessing, cpu-cores

When I run the following code on a Linux machine with 12 CPU cores, where 2 cores were saved for overhead or system function and 10 cores were consumed to run exactly the same task (a simple factorial calculation) simultaneously. And the result shows that, all cores are started at the almost same time since print function in stress_test() comes at almost the same time, BUT the same calculation takes significantyly different time to finish. What could have caused this? (lack of knowledge in Computer Science, really appreciate the help) Thanks in advance!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from datetime import datetime

def stress_test(args):
    cpu, value = args
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print(f'cpu starts: {cpu}')
    for i in range(value):
        value = value * i
    print(f"cpu: {cpu} time: {datetime.now() - start_time}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()
    cpu_count = cpu_count() - 2
    with Pool(cpu_count) as mp_pool:
        mp_pool.map(stress_test, [(cpu, int(2e8)) for cpu in range(cpu_count)])
    print(f"total: {datetime.now() - start_time}")
```

[print result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lx05.png)

run the code in Python 3.7.5 on a Ubuntu machine, expected the similar time consumption for the same factorial calculation under multiprocessing

Comment: Check `cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep MHz` it would probably show significant differences in CPU speeds  because of CPU frequency scaling. Depending on your kernel's governor you might be able to set it's algorithm to `performance`.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is move the datetime.now() out of the print statement, just in case it is delayed until IO occurs.  I would also defer ALL io until after the timing happens -- so record the start time, the end time, and the cpu, and don't print the start time etc until AFTER the task is complete - IO will result in you benchmarking IO instead of the actual work.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60351509/3889449

Comment: Note that the values will quickly become big so the functions might also be memory-bound. If so, multiple threads will not take the same time even when executed on different core having the same frequency. This is because the memory requests are generally not perfectly balanced, and also some cache lines will be already in cache while others will not. Not to mention the latency of memory request is not the same depending on the previous request (which are unpredicable in parallel computing). You can replace the integers with floats so avoid this effect and check if memory is an issue.